# Android app communication

Tags: java, android, generic-programming

Can somebody tell me the most convenient/ fastest way to communicate between two unrooted android devices. I'd like to write a game using this feature. The users would be standing close together. My first Idea was Bluetooth, a friend of mine suggested NFC. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: for doing it with NFC, the devices nearly have to touch each other, I don´t think it´s a good starting position for a game with much user interaction. It depends on the data size you want to transfer between the devices. For example, simple keywords like a string, bluetooth should do the job fast enough. Another way is to share over wifi network.

Comment: Thanks! As I said, Bluetooth was my first idea too.

Comment: Try creating a wifi hotspot.

Comment: This could be a solution too... I will have a look

Comment: NFC the devices have to be touching each other, which are not very good for gaming. Maybe for connection handshake. For close by devices the best options are bluetooth and WiFi. Bluetooth is simpler as you don't have to worry with options around hotspot, acces-point or WiFi-Direct; but WiFi is faster.